# Putting variables in the lists in Python

Tags: python, list, calculator

I would like to ask about how we can use variables to define the size of an array in Python (I mean list).I have written some piece of code below , could you please let me know what is wrong with the code?
Thanks..

```
   elif(op=='+') :
     size=int(input("Please enter how many numbers you want to add"))
     for x in range(0,size):
     print("Please enter the number",x+1) 
     inp=(input()) 
     num[x]=inp #<<<-----the error comes up when trying to run this expression
   for z in range(0,size):
     num[z]=num[z]+num[z+1]    
   print("The result is " , num[size])
```

Comment: What do you think is wrong? Indentation seems to be one problem.

Comment: is `num` already declared as python dict or a list??

Comment: Are you attempting to concatenate the string z  or add the numbers in inp as integers?

Comment: I want to add numbers in inp as integers , and make the num list by asking the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the problem in inp that @Daniel answers, the result of input() is a string. Thus, your code will just concatenate the numbers as you go through the list. Additionally, why are you constantly putting the concatenation into the list? Also when going the range, you will be appending the entered number of digits, but the index operation goes from 0 index to "size" index which is one more than are actually in the list.

```
 for z in range(0,size):
     num[z]=num[z]+num[z+1]    
 print("The result is " , num[size])
```

Thus when z == size -1, you will get an index out of range when attempting to reference num[z+1] as well as in your final print which tries to reference num[size]

additionally, if you are going to be adding rather than concatenating the input string, you should be saying inp = int(input())

```
size=int(input("Please enter how many numbers you want to add"))
mytotal = 0
for x in range(0,size):
    # The next two could have been on one line
    myval = int(input("Please enter the number"))
    mytotal += myval #This is split for clarity
print mytotal
```

Comment: It worked , thank you very much . In addition , if I want to add floating numbers , what should I type instead of int ?

Comment: @Ibrahim You would type float()

Answer (score 1):

Python lists are not initialized with a specific size, but grow dynamically. Use `append` to add elements:

```
size=int(input("Please enter how many numbers you want to add"))
num = [] # start with an empty list
for x in range(0,size):
    print("Please enter the number",x+1) 
    inp = input() 
    num.append(inp) # add elements
```

Comment: Note that the result of inpu() will set inp to a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Daniel.